# htaccess form submit auto redirect to clean url

Tags: php, .htaccess

i have a site

```
site.com/?w=thisworks
site.com/w/thisalsoworksmanually
```

i got this to work via htaccess

now i have a form... when it gets submitted

i get  `site.com/?w=stuffsubmitted`
i'm trying to have it auto redirect to `site.com/w/stuffsubmitted`

here is my htaccess that works

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^w/([^/]+)/?$ /index.php?w=$1 [L]
```

basically..i want to auto redirect to a clean url when form gets submitted..
if you need some more clarification..please ask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You redirect from the worng way, you redirect `site.com/w/stuffsubmitted` to `site.com/?w=stuffsubmitted` and you say that you want to redirect url with query string to that which don't have one.

```
RewriteCond %{query_string} w=(.*)
RewriteRule ^$ /w/%1? [R=301]
```

Comment: for some reason this is not cutting it.. any ideas

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution. Don't submit form with `method="GET"`.
If you have to submit `POST` form, you will write manually `action` url.